# Mold on the walls on the bathroom

Tags: bathroom, mold

I've been living on the same rented house for some years and on the last year's the mold on the house is intensifying. 
For example the bathroom is the worst case by far
[image]
[image]
This is an old house and the walls don't have any kind of insuation. 
The bathroom doesn't have an exhaust.

I don't want to spend much money on it; it's not my house and I will leave when I can.

I know I can put fresh paint and it will help for a while.

On your opinion what is the cheapest way to deal with this? Just cleaning?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the root problem is too much humidity in that area and fixing that properly would mean adding ventilation to get the warm and moist air outside.  Short of that, I can think of two things you might do:

1. Clean the area with a chlorine bleach solution (not 100% bleach) but something like 1 cup to a gallon of water.  Wear gloves as this will burn your skin.  And scrub the visible mold/mildew off.  The bleach will help to kill what's there.  Use a brush if you need to in order to get into cracks.  After that, you might treat the area with a commercial mold/mildew inhibiting product.  You should find something at a local grocery or home center.
2. After using the bath or shower you might place a portable fan in the room to help extract the humid air from the enclosed space.

Comment: Hello, normally I use a dehumidifier in the bathroom. It helps to clear the humidity, but still the mold doesn't disappear. We already used bleach (don't know if it was chlorine or not) and it is efficient to clean the mold but feels toxic.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used distilled vinegar for removing and killing mold. Chlorine bleach is good for non porous surfaces but it is a harsh chemical and can damage the surfaces and it gives off harsh fumes. Bleach cannot completely kill mold growing in porous materials. The chlorine in bleach cannot penetrate into porous surfaces such as drywall, wood and grout. The chlorine is left on the surface of porous materials and only the water component of the bleach is absorbed into the material, providing more moisture for the mold to feed on.

Vinegar is a mild acid which can kill 82% of mold species. However it also has the advantages of being natural and safe. Vinegar is non-toxic and doesn't give off dangerous fumes like bleach does.

To kill mold with vinegar, use white distilled vinegar which you can buy cheaply from the supermarket. Pour some vinegar into a spray bottle without watering it down. Spray the vinegar onto the moldy surface and leave it to sit for an hour.
Wipe clean the area with water and allow the surface to dry. Any smell from the vinegar should clear within a few hours.  Good luck.

Comment: Hello, your suggestion seems really great, I didn't find the distilled vinegar on the supermarkets near me, so I bought a natural vinegar for cleaning with lemon flavor, I will try it and see if it works, then I'll give feedback. Thanks!